# Angular - How to call object property from collection in Form input

Tags: angular, typescript

Please help, I have collection in angular component:

```js
 collection: collectionAbs[];
    
 export interface collectionAbs{
   name: string;
   prop: string;
   secondProp: number;
 }
```

And I initialize:

```js
    this.collection.forEach((item ,index) => {
      formGroup.addControl(index.toString() + "-prop", new FormControl('', [Validators.required])),
      formGroup.addControl(index.toString() + "-secondProp", new FormControl('', [Validators.required]))
    });
```

Object is initiated and I want to update properties in form. I have something like this:

```html
  <div *ngFor="let item of collection; let i = index" >
         <input type="text" name="collection[{{i}}].prop">
         <input type="number" name="collection[{{i}}].secondProp">
  </div>
```

But I haven't no idea how to assign now this values to my objects collection.
Maybe someone have better solution for this problem?

@Edit

FormGroup:

```js
 var formGroup: FormGroup;

 formGroup = new FormBuilder().group({
   anotherFormInputOne: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
   anotherFormInputTwo: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, I edited post.

Comment: Not exactly, I have a collection already created and I want to display the inputs for property for all objects. I just want to add a value to the property for each element.

Comment: I don`t know how to bind this input value to my object

Comment: You  should check how to use [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 1):

it should just be a case on submit of the form of doing:

```
    this.collection.forEach((item ,index) => {
      item.prop = formGroup.controls[index.toString() + "-prop"].value;
      item.secondProp = formGroup.controls[index.toString() + "-secondProp"].value;
    });
```